# Which component is used by lookbook.nu app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm searching the way to do this: 
[image]

How can I do it? It is present in the "lookbook.nu" app for iPhone

Comment: Which part? Beyond the buttons it's almost certainly all custom.

Comment: You should really tell us which exact part you mean. That girl is an image. Her hair is fake blonde.

Comment: I'm trying to do the little "tag number" and the movement (with zoom) thanks to the menu with arrows. Which components do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk

you can simply create a UIPopover on Iphone, but I think on ipad its much easier...Well take a look.